# How to change woocommerce each product total only in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have my checkout cart like this

product    price   quantity    total

apple       50     1            50

orange       40      1           40

I need to change the total on the right side to say 20

Code I tried  i will put on comment box

but it changes the price.I only need to change the total.Any ideas?

Comment: add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object )
 {
    $custom_price = 10; 
    foreach( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) 
   {
        $value['data']->price` = $custom_price;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Try with this piece of code in the functions.php file:

```
if(is_cart()){
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

    function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) 
    {
        global $woocommerce;
        $custom_price = $_POST["custom_prc"];

        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) 
        {
            $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
        }
    }
}
```